# Cache local File/Image in RAM

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, caching, blob

### The setup

I am working on a vuejs **WebApp** that loads and **displays a lot of images (~10-20k)**. These images are opened from a **network drive**.

When the user opens a folder from that drive I collect all files and then create URLs for them.

```
// get blob objects for all files
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
const filePromises: Promise<File>[] = getFilePromises(dirHandle);
const files = await Promise.all(filePromises);

const imageURLs = files.map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file))
```

In there `getFilePromises()` simply recursively loops over `dirHandle.values()` and pushes `value.getFile()` to the promises array.

These image urls are then used to render a grid `<img>` tags. The grid is of course virtualized to not overload the DOM.

### The problem

Now the problem is that the **network drive is very slow** sometimes.

Never the less the **above code runs pretty fast** (couple of seconds only for 10k images). But it really **takes forever** until the first **images are displayed/loaded** in the grid. Until then I only see empty boxes.
[image]
(I display the images with a border and a fixed size, which is why I see the boxes before the image is loaded).

Then step by step the images slowly appear.

Repeating this with the same images stored on **local SSD** leads to nearly **instant displaying**. So it's definitely a loading issue.

### Theories and Questions

As the delay happens **after the above code has finished** running, I have 2 theories and 2 corresponding questions:

1. The blobs will **eventually all get loaded into the RAM/heap** automatically. But this process is running in the background after the above code has finished.

   - => **How can I await that process / know when it is finished?**
2. The blobs are **only referenced** to the network drive and are only loaded in RAM on demand.

   - => **How can I cache all images in RAM instantly?**

Can someone explain exactly what's happening there? I though awaiting the file blob object meant I await it beeing loaded into RAM. But that's clearly not the case.

### Clarification

I know there's no way around waiting x minutes until all images are pulled from the drive.

But I'd rather pull them all at once, **show a loading animation** to the user and then deliver him a fluent user experience than showing him and empty grid without him knowing what's going on.

10k images are only about 500Mb so this should definitely fit in the RAM.

Thank you all!:)

Comment: For network drive - you open too much files at once, and they wait, timeout even?

Comment: @Seti Sorry, I clarified my question: The given code (=creating of the file array) happens really quick. And it seems like everything is done (no lag in the app). But the images are just not displayed yet, I only the the empty divs. Then after waiting several minutes step by step they appear.

Comment: @Seti So there is no timeout or crash. It's just that I wait so long until they are displayed. I know I have to wait anyway but I'd like to wait with displaying the grid until everything is in RAM. So that I could display a loading progress bar or something like that to indicate that something is still going on.

Comment: Use, because ti has to connect, fetch all data, and it TAKES a while for it to be sent over. As the @Dimava wrote - you need to download it sequentially. You can for example fetch whole directory, and then just show empty images, and check if that image should be shown - then lazy load them if they are not in cache, if they are - just show them from cache. `Promise.all` will wait for all to finish, or (WORST CASE SCENARIO) will break on first error, but promises underneth will still continue theirs work (really bad thing)

Comment: @Seti I don't really understand this. The Promise.all for awaiting the files does only take a couple of seconds. But the images are definitely not in RAM directly afterwards.

Maybe you could also comment on my answer postet below - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Now I figured a way how I can force the file blobs to be in RAM, so this basically answers my question:

After having the array of Files I read their content into an ArrayBuffer. This to my understanding than has to be in RAM. Afterwards I recreate blobs / files from those ArrayBuffers. The resulting files are then in RAM.

```
function cacheFilesInRam(files: File[]): File[] {
 const arrayBufferPromises = this.files.map((file) => file.arrayBuffer());
 const arrayBuffers = await Promise.all(arrayBufferPromises);
 const blobs = arrayBuffers.map(
   (buffer) => new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/jpeg" })
 );
 return blobs.map((blob, idx) => new File([blob], files[idx].name));
}
```

The important part for me is, that after the code as finished, I am sure all images are completely in RAM. So after the initial waiting time the application runs super fast and there are **no loading times any more**.

The question is: **Is this bad practice?**. Or are there any arguments speaking against this practice? Appreciate any comments!

Comment: Well, if you need them only as images you'd better to toDataUrl those blobs instead of Fileing them

Comment: I mean, objectURL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static

Comment: @Dimava But I'm already using URL.createObjectURL(file). The problem is, that the creation of the URL does not trigger the loading of the image.

Comment: Then try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode to load it into GPU RAM. But I did mean to toObjectUrl the blobs, no point inmaking hen fines again

Answer (score 0):

1. Load images **sequentially**. If you load images one by one rather then 1000 at once, 5-10 threads is optimal for http images (browser uses 8 threads iirc), dunno about drive but don't use over 20 unleast you have really high ping

```
for (let [index, file] of files.entries()) imgs[i] = await load(file)
```

2. Create actual image element `document.createElement('img').src = dataScc; img.onload = resolve(img)`
   so you when image is loaded into memory
3. Use `window.caches` if you want to seamlessly store the data on user's PC
   (in case you want it to be fast without)
4. Try do display images immediately - highly prioritize loading visible images
   If the loading of 10'000 images takes 100s of seconds, loading of 100 images on the screen will take just seconds

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm actually struggling to understand what step exactly loads the blob into memory, so that it can be displayed.
Because awaiting the file promise obviously does not mean it's ready in memory. Is it only loaded when it's referenced in an image element. Or already when I create an object url?

Comment: would be happy if you could comment on my solution.