# Where are js blobs stored

Tags: javascript, memory, blob, ram

I'd like to understand at want point in time the content of a file blob is actually read into RAM.

I'll use the following scenario where a user simply selects a local image from his disk. The image is then displayed afterwards.

```
const [fileHandle] = await showOpenFilePicker();  // (1)
const file = await fileHandle.getFile();        // (2)
const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)        // (3)
document.getElementById("img").src = imgUrl;  // (4)
```

1. At what step (1-4) is the content of the file actually fully loaded into RAM?
2. How does this work before that? Does the blob only hold a reference to the file, but does not fully load it? How can this work with files on network drives?

The reason why I'm asking is my concrete usecase [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77058323/cache-local-file-image-in-ram). When doing above steps with a bigger amount of images from a slow network drive, I observed that after the above code finished running, the blob does not seem to be in RAM (the image takes a while to be displayed and it's not immediately visible in the 'sources' tab in chrome developer tools).

Would really like to understand what exactly is going on there - thank you all!

Comment: Hm. When you set an image source the image still needs to be loaded and rendered—you’re not creating base 64 image data, you’re just seeing an image URL that needs to be loaded.

Comment: @DaveNewton So the object url is kind of a reference to some bytes on the disk, not to bytes already in RAM? 

And creating the URL does not trigger the loading? Is it the just when setting the <img> src, that the content of the file is read?

Comment: A URL is a URL—it’s like the difference between the URL string you type into a browser bar (a url) and hitting return (fetching the content). A browser doesn’t know what image an `<img>` should fetch until it has a source. You set the source with a URL; now the image can fetch. This is visible in the network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought that `createObjectURL` loads the file and creates a URL that indicates a place in RAM. Will deleting the file after `createObjectURL` but before `src = imageUrl` cause the image to not load?

Comment: @Konrad Thinking back now I’m not sure—in my head I was thinking as base64 and I’d have to try this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a definitive answer, but I tested it and...

`URL.createObjectURL(file)` doesn't load up the image, at least not in chrome

### Explanation:

1. Firstly, I created the URL using this code:

```
const [fileHandle] = await showOpenFilePicker();
const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

2. Ran the code and chose a file
3. Deleted the file from the hard drive
4. Loaded the image using:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = imgUrl;
```

5. The image didn't load, I got `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error

When I skipped the 3rd point the image loaded as expected

It seems like `URL.createObjectURL(file)` saves the path to the file on the hard drive. Or at least it looks like this

Comment: This seems right based on the docs, but I also scratched my head a little around this function in general ‍♂️

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how the browser can hold a reference to something on the filesystem. I was thinking the sandbox idea forbits the browser to have direct access to hard disk. But I seem to be wrong...

Comment: And does holding the an active object url to a file object prevent the actual file object from beeing garbage collected?